# GCS Hadoop connector error: ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer ls: No FileSystem for scheme gs

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to setup [hadoop-connectors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors) on my local Ubuntu 20.04 and running the test command `hadoop fs -ls gs://my-bucket` but I keep getting errors like the following:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls gs://my-bucket
2020-08-22 03:29:06,976 WARN fs.FileSystem: Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem Unable to get public no-arg constructor
2020-08-22 03:29:06,977 WARN fs.FileSystem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer
2020-08-22 03:29:06,977 WARN fs.FileSystem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
ls: No FileSystem for scheme "gs"
```

Note that I can access the bucket using `gsutil ls gs://my-bucket`.

I have downloaded `gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar` from [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage) and placed it inside `/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib`. I hope this is the right place for this jar file?

I've configured `core-site.xml` with the properties listed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md#configure-hadoop) and also set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to my service account key file. In `hadoop-env.sh` I've exported

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ 
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH+="$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*.jar"
```

Not sure if I've set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` correctly and if `hadoop` recognizes the jar files inside `/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib`? And what is the difference to `/usr/local/hadoop/lib`?

Here is the relevant content of `core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl</name>
  <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS</value>
  <description>The AbstractFileSystem for gs: uris.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.project.id</name>
  <value>my-project-id</value>
  <description>
    Optional. Google Cloud Project ID with access to GCS buckets.
    Required only for list buckets and create bucket operations.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>
    Whether to use a service account for GCS authorization.
    Setting this property to `false` will disable use of service accounts for
    authentication.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile</name>
  <value>/path/to/service-account.json</value>
  <description>
    The JSON key file of the service account used for GCS
    access when google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable is true.
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 3.3.0
Source code repository https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r aa96f1871bfd858f9bac59cf2a81ec470da649af
Compiled by brahma on 2020-07-06T18:44Z
Compiled with protoc 3.7.1
From source with checksum 5dc29b802d6ccd77b262ef9d04d19c4
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.3.0.jar
```

bashrc:

```
...

export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh

export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
```

Comment: May you check if you can find `gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar` in the output of the `hadoop classpath --glob` command?

Comment: Thanks @IgorDvorzhak, I've just booted my machine and `hadoop classpath --glob`  is able to find the `gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar`. Also `hadoop fs -ls gs://my-bucket` is working now. It seems I should have rebooted before trying to execute the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that rebooting helped to solve the issue. After a reboot the command `hadoop fs -ls gs://my-bucket` works and lists the content of the bucket as expected.

Thanks to @IgorDvorzhak providing the command: `hadoop classpath --glob` to check if the `gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar` can be found. I used:

```
hadoop classpath --glob | grep gcs-connector
```